# Creating a dictionary of strings and list of strings

Tags: c#, strings, linq, hash-map

I have a `List` of objects, `List<myObject> objectList`, and each object contains a `List` of strings like so:

```
myObject: StringList( "A_1", "B_1", "C_1", "D_1", "E_1", "F_1" )  
myObject: StringList( "A_2", "B_2", "C_1", "D_2", "E_2", "F_1" )  
myObject: StringList( "A_2", "B_3", "C_1", "D_3", "E_2", "F_1" )
```

I'm trying to merge the lists into a dictionary of: `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where the final results will look like so:

```
Dictionary: { [A:1,2]  [B:1,2,3]  [C:1]  [D:1,2,3]  [E:1,2]  [F:1] }
```

Here is what I have done, and it does work:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (myObject result in objectList)
{
    foreach (var item in result.StringList)
    {
        string Key = item.Split('_')[0];
        string Value = item.Split('_')[1];

        List<string> sValue = new List<string>();
        bool exists = dict.TryGetValue(Key, out sValue);

        if (exists && !sValue.Contains(Value))
        {
            sValue.Add(Value);
            dict[Key] = sValue;
        }
        else if (!exists)
        {
            sValue = sValue ?? new List<string>();
            sValue.Add(Value);
            dict.Add(Key, sValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, where I don't have to use two `foreach` loops? Is there a way to do it without using any `foreach` loops?

I have tried using lambda but this is as far as I got:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (myObject result in objectList)
{
    dict = result.StringList.Select(x => x.Split('_'))
                            .GroupBy(x => x[0])
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(g => g[1]).ToList());
}
```

The problem is that the expression keeps overwriting any existing entries in the dictionary each time I iterate through the loop.

Is there a way to keep the existing entries, groupby the Key and add to the existing list of values but don't duplicate any values?

I think the answer lies in this part of the expression:

```
x => x.Select(g => g[1]).ToList()
```

but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Did you try SelectMany?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just get rid of the outer `foreach` as well:

```
dict = objectList.SelectMany(x => x.StringList)
       .Select(x => x.Split('_'))
       .GroupBy(x => x[0])
       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(g => g[1]).Distinct().ToList());
```

SelectMany retrieves all the `StringList`s and flattens them into one single list:

```
"A_1", "B_1", ..., "F_1", "A_2", "B_2", ...
```

Comment: I think you want a distinct in there as well so that A is `1,2` rather than `1,2,2`.

Comment: `x => x.Select(g => g[1]).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Note that [`Distinct` destroys order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq), so it might be `1,2` or `2,1`.

Comment: @Heinzi - Thanks so much! This works perfectly!  Much simpler and more elegant.  For the life of me, I couldn't figure this out...a million times thank you!

Comment: @TimS. - Yes, you are right.  I added a quick .OrderBy() after the .Distinct and it fixed things right up.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tim: it probably doesn't guarantee to preserve order for all LINQ providers, but in LINQ to objects (i.e. `IEnumerable` extensions) it should preserve order (it seems like the most logical way to implement it: *for each item in input sequence, yield return it unless it's already present in a hashset*.).

Comment: @Groo Like a comment at my link says, "what you say could be true [that it preserves first-found order], but it would be a bad idea to rely on that behavior" (because it is documented as being an *unordered* sequence, you should treat it as such). Also, I don't know that `objectList` had it sorted to begin with, the example just happens to have it so (I think).

Comment: @Tim: that's news for me, I must admit, but that's probably the safest bet if they say so (even though I don't see how and why would one implement an unordered `Distinct` without some extra effort). The puzzling thing, however, was that OP wrote that it *fixed things right up*, even though I am pretty sure it didn't change anything. :)

Comment: @Groo I could write it with the least possible effort, in a way that destroys the order: `return new HashSet<T>(source);`

Comment: Hm, actually, that does seem to retain the insertion order (again, just as an implementation detail).